# Cleaner / smarter way to use a for loop

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a DataGridView with 35 columns and I was wondering how to programmatically do a FOR loop to set the header text alignment to center only from column 4 through 20.  I know how to do it column by column but I'm sure there must be a faster / smarter way to do it.  See below the code I'm using:

```
alunos_detDataGridView.Columns[4].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
alunos_detDataGridView.Columns[5].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `for` loop to increase variable (`i`in this case) progressively from 4 to 20 and use this variable as index of column:

```
for(int i = 4; i <= 20; i++)
{
       alunos_detDataGridView.Columns[i].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Enumerable.Range(4,16).ToList().ForEach(i=> alunos_detDataGridView.Columns[i].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter);
```

Any kind of loop will solve your problem

Comment: You are enumerating wrongly and at such a horrible performance-wise perspective. Why enumerate 4-16 (when the OP asked 4-20) 3 times when a simple for loop does it in one? (First enumeration on the range, second on the ToList and third on the ForEach.